# What is plastic flow?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, material-science

I read in a book named *Introduction To Tribology* that when a soft material is in contact with hard material, the soft surface will undergo a plastic flow because it is pressed by the hard asperities of the hard materials. I didn't understand this - what is the meaning of plastic flow and does the stress play some role in the formation of the plastic flow? Please inform me if you know about this.

Comment: A plastic deformation occurs when the material does not return to its original shape. How much stress it takes to make a material undergo plastic flow depends on the material.

Answer (score 5):

A plastic flow is a

> deformation of a material that remains rigid under stresses of less than a certain intensity but that behaves under severer stresses approximately as a Newtonian fluid.

In other words, let's say you have a sheet of plastic (though plastic flow can happen to not-plastic items) and you put it across two blocks and put weight on it, and measured the stress on the plastic, sort of like in the picture below.

[image: plastic testing]

So you are putting weight on it, and the measured stress goes up and up, and you don't even see it bow a bit. Then, all of a sudden, the stress meter hits a certain point and the plastic doesn't snap, but sort of behaves like a liquid, flowing instead of bending or breaking like in the diagram below. That's plastic flow.

[image: example of plastic flow]

(Quote from http://www.dictionary.com/browse/plastic-flow). Hope this helps!

Comment: Plastic flow (a dislocation mediated effect) is distinct from creep (a point defect mediated effect).

Comment: No problem. I'm glad it helped you out.